# Regular expression to validate City field

Tags: regex

I am creating a regular expression to validate a city field. With the following code, I only can validate a City field with one space:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$");
```

Any advice about how to improve my regular expression to validate city fields with more than one space?

Well, finally I am using this regexp:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\\s+|-)[a-zA-Z]+)*$");
```

But now I am having a problem with accents  How do I add accents to my city field?

Comment: Can you add the language you're using as a tag, please?

Comment: Also, which _human_ language is this for? Do you accept `北京`? How about `Düsseldorf`?

Comment: And what about Villefranche sur Saône, and Stoke on Trent? Or Little Cottonwood Creek Valley, in Utah? These sort of validations just serve to make certain people unable to use your site. Don't use them.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: their regexp actually does handle that (up to `ô`). The problem seems to be merely that `Stoke on <two spaces> Trent` is not accepted.

Comment: Regexes won't suit your need IMHO. If you really need to verify city names, you should find a database listing them, and then check if the city name the user entered can be found in the database.

Comment: @Michelle: Right, I misread it I thought he tried to *not* allow it. The fact is of course that his given regexp *does* allow it.

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Comment: @AndyLester - I wish I could upvote that comment 2,000,000 times and automatically add it to 90% of the regex questions on this site.

Comment: @jahroy: Do what I do.  Keep a folder in Evernote of stock answers that you paste as responses.  Besides the one above, I have one for "Don't parse HTML with regexes", one for "You are leaving yourself open to SQL injection", one for "Parsing URLs with regexes is usually better done in the host language with existing functions", etc etc.  After you've written a good answer the 2nd time, it's time to file it away for the next time you need to pull it out.

Comment: That's pretty funny... I tend to just use links to favorites.  It would be nice if today's kids could just learn to read, write, and search the interwebz!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use an alternation instead of a character class:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\\s+|-)[a-zA-Z]+)*$");
```

Comment: @Killercam you are a true benefactor, +1 for that.

Comment: What is this part doing? (?:(?:\\s+|-)

Comment: @JohnMerlino: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. `|` is used to make an alternation. `\\s` is a character class that contains all whitespace characters. `(?:(?:\\s+|-)[a-zA-Z]+)` means: *letters preceded by either one or more whitespace characters, or a `-`*

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest way would be this:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$
```

Or if you prefer, you can do this, which will ensure that the string doesn't start or end with a whitespace or hyphen:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s-]+[a-zA-Z]$
```

Of course, don't forget to escape the `\` in Java:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\s-]+[a-zA-Z]$");
```

Comment: This first one accepts e.g `"------"`, the second `"A----B"` - both are hardly valid city names.

Comment: @thg435 `"A (20 spaces) B"` doesn't seem like a particularly valid city name either.

Comment: @thg435 If you only want to allow valid city names, validate against a list of existing cities.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z\\s-]+$");
```

Comment: This works if you consider dozens of tabs and space characters with a few random hyphens to be a valid city name.